# Помогите написать программу на С++

Tags: c++

Определить, содержит ли данный текст символы, отличные от букв и пробела.

У меня не получается составить программу и вообще как работать со строками в таких задачах. Я пытался сделать эту задачу по кодам каждого символа. Вот что получилось.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  string s;
  cout << "введите строку: ";
  getline(cin, s);
  if (s >= '97' && s <= '122'; s = '32')
    cout << "текст не содержит символы отличные от букв и пробела";
  else
    cout << "текст содержит символы отличные от букв и пробела";
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вы должны в цикле проверять символыЮ а не сравнивать строку с числом.

Answer (score 1):

1. Вначале нужно определить что такое буква. Судя по вашему коду вы проверяете только на вхождение в диапазон `a`..`z`. Т.е. для вас буква это буква латинского алфавита в нижнем регистре. Я бы добавил еще проверку на верхний регистр. Это если кириллицу мы за буквы не считаем
2. Проверка вида

   ```c
   if (s >= '97'
   ```

   ошибочна. Либо проверяйте по кодам, тогда никаких кавычек

   ```c
   if (s >= 97
   ```

   либо в кавычках пишите символ

   ```c
   if (s >= 'a'
   ```
3. Проверять нужно **каждый** символ строки, а не всю строку

Итого

```cpp
bool letterAndSpace = true;
for (int i = 0; letterAndSpace && i < s.length; i++) {
  char cur = s[i];
  letterAndSpace =
    (cur == ' ') ||
    (cur >= 'A' && cur <= 'Z') ||
    (cur >= 'a' && cur <= 'z');
}
if (letterAndSpace)
  cout << "текст не содержит символы отличные от букв и пробела";
else
  cout << "текст содержит символы отличные от букв и пробела";
```

Comment: Ага, спасибо!! Но у меня пара вопросов 1) в цикле for в s.length пишет что s не был объявлен

Comment: И ещё я немного не понимаю зачем здесь cur?

Comment: @Igor Так это не вся программа, а только часть. s нужно объявить и инициализировать 2) `cur` нужен, чтобы не писать каждый раз `s[i]`